# Warn users about losing privileges when starting bounty

Tags: discussion, privileges

I mostly use SuperUser in read&comment mode only. I could comment, since I had 100+ reputation, thanks to my profile on StackOverflow. Recently I started a bounty on [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/203294/custom-one-key-keyboard-shortcuts-in-outlook-2010-or-2013) and I was stupid enough to grant all of my 100 reputation for it.

Now I cannot comment and I cannot even ask a question in Meta! I find this very annoying. It would be of much help, if I was warned about it when started the bounty. I did not even know such privileges exist!

What do you think about warnings on lost privileges, when you start a bounty?

Comment: Moved as per request. Might be good to be a little more careful where you post this sorta thing

Comment: @JourneymanGeek He doesn't have enough rep left to post on meta. 5 rep is required http://superuser.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta

Comment: [metase] dupe: [Notify user when setting a bounty will revoke a privilege](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11930)

Answer (score 2):

As per the [appropriate help pages](https://superuser.com/help/bounty)

> If your new reputation brings you below the requirement for any privileges, you will lose access to those privileges.

Might get complicated if you had to warned every time this would happen. Or if you lost two permissions and so on.

Granted, this is more of an issue for a new user than one with enough rep that posting bounties would be a good idea.

Comment: New users get hit the hardest and are more likely to be unaware of this behavior. The system could easily check whether for the selected amount of reputation in the "start a bounty" dialog, any privileges would be lost, and if so, list them. If none are lost, nothing changes (except for a new AJAX request without visible effects). I really don't see much of a downside to reminding users it's not just fake internet points they would lose, but also e.g. chat, meta, or comment privileges.